# Chronicle-Map recovery

Tags: chronicle-map

I'm reading this

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc

And it says it could be in corrupted state if a process is killed while "accessing" it.

I would imagine it means while it's "writing" to it?

If I only have a process that's read only and that's getting killed, would it corrupt the map?

Thanks,
- Mag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Read only" access to a Chronicle Map still writes to it's memory when it acquires locks. If a reader process is killed while holding a lock, a segment is not going to be accessible until the recovery is done.